# How to install latest release ubuntu without losing data files

Tags: upgrade

I'm running 12.04 and want to upgrade to the latest stable version.  How do I do that without losing my data files?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, there is no way to upgrade from 12.04 to 13.10 directly unless you reinstall Ubuntu completely, which will lead to a loss of data.

My advice is, backup your important files - this is important. Whether or not your files are supposed to be deleted does not matter - ***accidents can and will happen***.

After backing up, you can upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10, then to 13.04, then to 13.10 by running

```
do-release-upgrade
```

in a terminal.

However, this is **extremely slow** as you will be upgrading 3 times. My recommendation is, copy your files to another device (perhaps using the 13.10 Live CD) and reinstall your Ubuntu.

Summary: Two choices.

1. Backup files and upgrade 3 times using `do-release-upgrade`, or
2. Reinstall Ubuntu 13.10 after copying files elsewhere.